# When exactly onReceive from BroadcastReceiver is called?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I know that `onReceive` from `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main thread (UI). Does it mean that my all methods like `onStart`, `onDestroy`, `onClick()` etc have to be finished before `onReceive` will be called? Or can `onReceive` be called while I'm for example in the middle of `onStart` method, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
        if (networkChangeReceiver != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            context.registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
        method1();
        //here connection changes -> can onReceive be called here?
        method2();
        method3();
        (...)

}
```

Comment: This is possible if there is a long running task `onReceive()` will call on time . It doesn't have to do anything with lifecycle method . It has its own lifecycle Register/Unregister.

Answer (score 0):

Even if onReceive it's called in UI thread don't expect it to appear only after you finish your stuff in onStart/onCreate or whatever. The broadcast can receive at anytime, most likely somewhere in between or your logic, so your assumtion is correct: can be called right in the middle of your code from onStart() for example.

Comment: You can read more about android Handlers and Looper. You can think of broadcast receiver as a callback if it helps you
Basically the android ui thread has a looper and a queue of stuff that has to be done. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a

Comment: I assume the onReceive call is added to the ui thread looper. I thought it guarantees that method like onStart() will be finished before next message (onRecive) from the message queue will be called.

Comment: again: if `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive` is called on the main UI thread so how it can be called in the meddle of other UI method like `Activity#onStart` for example? and yes, i know what `Looper` / `Handler` / `MessageQueue` is

Comment: most likely that it will be finished since you are registering exactly on that method. Wondering in what practical case u expect this to be a problem?

Comment: if you want to be sure that onStart has ran all it's code, then register the receiver at the end of onStart

Comment: I know that I can register at the end of the method. But I want to be sure that my other methods like onClick, onResume, .. has finished. I asked this question because I wasn't sure if main thread looper guarantees finishing other UI methods.

Comment: @AppiDevo if two methods are called on the same thread (main UI thread in that case) there is no way they will interrupt each other, no way